# Loop through columns in a dataframe and add a new column to the dataframe with the first non null value found. Using PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I'm new to PySpark trying to figure out how to achieve the desired results below.

I have a dataframe which contains several columns. I want to loop through columns id1, id2 and id3 and once the first non null value is found a new column should be added with this value. After finding the value no more loop for that record is needed.

The dataframe:

| name | id1 | hobby | id2 | gender | id3 | language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | AAA-BBB | Fishing |  | M | AAA-BBB | Eng |
| Louis |  |  | ABC-DDD | M |  |  |
| Peter | DSA-SDF | Hunting | DSA-SDF | M | DSA-SDF | Eng |

The desired dataframe:

| name | id1 | hobby | id2 | gender | id3 | language | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | AAA-BBB | Fishing |  | M | AAA-BBB | Eng | AAA-BBB |
| Louis |  |  | ABC-DDD | M |  |  | ABC-DDD |
| Peter | DSA-SDF | Hunting | DSA-SDF | M | DSA-SDF | Eng | DSA-SDF |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there just three columns?

Comment: No, there are 7 columns which I want to loop through, all with different names, the values can be the same or null. I want to find the first none null value in these column and create a new column with this value

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df = (df.withColumn("id", functions.when(df["id1"].isNotNull(), df["id1"])
                                   .when(df["id2"].isNotNull(), df["id2"])
                                   .when(df["id3"].isNotNull(), df["id3"])))

df.show()
+-----+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| name|    id1|  hobby|    id2|gender|    id3|language|   test|     id|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| Mike|AAA-BBB|Fishing|   null|     M|AAA-BBB|     Eng|AAA-BBB|AAA-BBB|
|Louis|   null|   null|ABC-DDD|     M|   null|    null|ABC-DDD|ABC-DDD|
|Peter|DSA-SDF|Hunting|DSA-SDF|     M|DSA-SDF|     Eng|DSA-SDF|DSA-SDF|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```